# Is it possible to have listener on EditTextPreference?

Tags: android, edittextpreference

I currently have a Settings Preference Activity consisting of one EditTextPreference. I would like to have an listener when the Dialog closes, so I could run some code

I've tried some of the methods listed here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/EditTextPreference.html,
but to no luck.

Am I missing something?

EDIT:

```
protected void onDialogClosed (boolean positiveResult)
{
    Log.d("tag", "dialog");
}
```

I used this method for example wich should print the tag each time the dialog is closed, but it is not working like I thought it would

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should listen to the [preference change](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html#Listening), not to the dialog close event.